# Let $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ for sufficiently large $p$. Does $\Delta u_n^+ \rightharpoonup \Delta u^+$ in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

On a smooth and bounded domain, let $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ for sufficiently large $p$. Does $\Delta u_n^+ \rightharpoonup \Delta u^+$ in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Here $u^+$ means the  positive part of $u$.

I think it is no, since we only have weak convergence in $L^2$ of the Laplacians of $u_n$.. but do I miss anything?

Comment: Do you mean $(\Delta u_n)^+$ or $\Delta (u_n^+)$. Note that the second one might not be defined. For the first one the answer is *no*, since $\Delta u_n$ can be an arbitrary sequence in $L^p(\Omega)$ which converges only weakly.

Comment: @gerw I meant the first. Thanks...

Comment: @gerw But isn't the $L^2$ norm of $(\Delta u_n)^+$ bounded by $L^2$ norm of $(\Delta u_n)$?? Thus there is a weak limit?

Comment: Yes, it is bounded. But the weak limit of $(\Delta u_n)^+$ is not $(\Delta u)^+$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, let $u_n(x) = n^{-2} \sin nx$ (the domain being a one-dimensional interval such as $[0, 1]$.). Then $u_n'' = -\sin nx$ which converges weakly (in any $L^p$ with $p<\infty$) to zero. So, $u_n\to 0$ weakly in $W^{2, p}$.

On the other hand, $(u_n'')^+ $ does not converge weakly to zero, because
$$
\int_0^1 (u_n'')^+ \to \frac{1}{\pi}
$$ 
(the average value of $(\sin x)^+$ is $1/\pi$).